# Position controls on a circle

Tags: c#, winforms, math, drawing, trigonometry

I am trying to spread panels (9 in my example) on a circle that I have drawn.

I am using c# winforms.

I have tried many variations of my code but I'm not getting what I want and started to get confused.

Eventually I want something like that: 
[image: Manually spread panels]

I am not really sure how to put the center of my panels on the corresponding points on the circle using the angles. 
Here's my code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    List<Panel> plist = new List<Panel>();
    Rectangle circ_rect = new Rectangle();
    const int Num_Screens = 9;
    const int margin = 15;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
    }

    private void Generate_Panels()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
        {
            Panel p = new Panel();
            p.BackColor = Color.LightSkyBlue;
            p.Size = new Size(250, 150);
            p.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
            p.Name = "panel_" + ((i + 1).ToString());
            plist.Add(p);
        }
    }

    private void Generate_Circle()
    {
        //Create panels
        Generate_Panels();

        //Set circle coord
        Point circ_center = new Point(Width / 2, Height / 2);
        Size circ_Size = new Size(Height - margin, Height - margin);
        circ_center = new Point((circ_center.X - (circ_Size.Width  / 2)), 
                                (circ_center.Y - (circ_Size.Height / 2)));
        circ_rect = new Rectangle(circ_center, circ_Size);

        float radius = circ_Size.Width / 2;
        float angle = 0.0f;
        Point loc = Point.Empty;
        Point rect_center = Point.Empty;

        for (int i = 0; i < plist.Count; i++)
        {
            rect_center = new Point((plist[i].Width / 2), (plist[i].Height / 2));
            angle = 360 * ((i + 1f) / 9);
            loc.X = (int)(radius * Math.Cos(angle * Math.PI / 180)) + circ_center.X;
            loc.Y = (int)(radius * Math.Sin(angle * Math.PI / 180)) + circ_center.Y;

            plist[i].Location = new Point(loc.X - (plist[i].Width  / 2) + circ_rect.X,
                                          loc.Y - (plist[i].Height / 2) + circ_rect.Y);

            this.Controls.Add(plist[i]);
        }
    }

    private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
        e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(Pens.Red, circ_rect);
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Generate_Circle();

    }
}
```

Comment: In `plist[i].Location = new Point(...` there is no need to add `circ_rect.X/Y`, since this offset is already included in `circ_center`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having `r` as radius of a circle with center of `(0,0)` in a Cartesian coordinate system, we can calculate coordinate of a on the circle based on the angle:

- `x = r * cos(degree)` and  `y = r * sin(degree)`

In C# `Sin` and `Cos` methods, accept radians, so we should convert degree to radians using the following formula.

- `radians = Math.PI * degree / 180.0`

The next step is converting the Cartesian coordinate system values to the form coordinate values:

- `panel.X = x + center.X - panel.Width/2`
- `panel.Y = center.Y - y - panel.Height/2`

The next step is calculating the angles. You can set angles manually or you can calculate them by setting an angle as start angle (like 90) and adding a value (like 40, 360/count) as step to the angles.

[image]

**Example**

```
public partial class Form1 : Form {
    Rectangle circle;
    List<Panel> panels;
    List<int> angles;
    public Form1() {
        InitializeComponent();
        ResizeRedraw = true;
        angles = Enumerable.Range(0, 9).Select(x => 90 + x * 40).ToList();
        panels = Enumerable.Range(0, 9).Select(x => new Panel() {
            Size = new Size(100, 40),
            BackColor = Color.LightSkyBlue
        }).ToList();
        this.Controls.AddRange(panels.ToArray());
    }
    protected override void OnLayout(LayoutEventArgs levent) {
        base.OnLayout(levent);
        int padding = 50;
        int radius = Math.Min(ClientSize.Width, ClientSize.Height) / 2 - padding;
        Point center = new Point(ClientSize.Width / 2, ClientSize.Height / 2);
        circle = new Rectangle(center.X - radius, center.Y - radius,
             2 * radius, 2 * radius);
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            var x = (int)(radius * Math.Cos(Math.PI * angles[i] / 180.0)) + center.X;
            var y = center.Y - (int)(radius * Math.Sin(Math.PI * angles[i] / 180.0));
            panels[i].Left = x - (panels[i].Width / 2);
            panels[i].Top = y - (panels[i].Height / 2);
        }
    }
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e) {
        base.OnPaint(e);
        e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
        e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(Pens.Red, circle);
    }
}
```

Comment: OP already had most of what was written here; would have been more helpful to directly point out where their error was.

Comment: @meowgoesthedog The main problem is to converting Cartesian coordinate to form coordinate. The next one, is the way they calculate the angles which leads to not aligned panels.

Comment: Yes I was just pointing out that OP already understood all of the math in your original edit, but you didn't directly point out the lines of code which were wrong (which you have done in the new edit).

Comment: Would you mind explaining angles = Enumerable.Range(... line?

Comment: @Meeseeks You're welcome :) It's similar to using a normal `for` loop. You can simple replace them with `for`, for example: `angles  = new List<int>();` `for(var o=0; i<9; i++){angles.Add(90 + i * 40);}`. If you are not familiar with linq right now, ignore them for now and use a `for` loop. But for future, it's better to learn linq :)

Comment: @Meeseeks Just make sure you take a [tour] to know how to accept/vote answers :)

Comment: @RezaAghaei Alright thanks!! I up voted the answer but it doesn't work publicly unless I have +15 reputation

Comment: You can use your power to accept the answer by click on checkmark near the answer. Not only it shows you have approved the solution, it also has +2 reputation for you!